# Clear placeholder with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, automation

I'm developing a script with Selenium Webdriver where it should be done a fill a text field with placeholder. I am using the following command, but the script is not filling informed on what string and also does not remove the placeholder field. I'd like suggestions for this:

`pageobjects.FindElement(By.XPath(objectname)).Clear();`

Comment: What is wrong with placeholder? I mean, why are you trying to make it disappear? It is not a value of the field. Just start filling the field with text.

Comment: What type of Object is `pageobjects`?  Is it an instance of WebDriver, or is it an instance of a custom class?

Comment: Agreed with the above, the `placeholder` isn't the **value** of a given element, it's just another attribute on that element, (in the same way that `class` and `id` are) and it's the responsibility of the browser *how* to render that (IE <=9 fail at that horribly, for instance). By that very definition, it is not something that can be removed through Selenium, or at least, through a normal `Clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clear the placeholder text.  This should be all you need to do, using the `SendKeys()` method:

```
pageobjects.FindElement(By.XPath(xpathOfObject)).SendKeys(textToSend);
```

If you find that still nothing is happening, then (without looking at more of your code) there are three possiblities that come to mind:

1. Your code is finding a different element than the one you're trying to find.
2. Your code is not finding an element at all, and is silently failing because you're catching an exception and swallowing it.
3. The element is read only.